# Mongodb java driver cannot recognize my field

Tags: java, mongodb

I add a field manually to some of my documents in mongodb. It's a date field: creationDate.
This is the script that I write in mongodb terminal:

```
    var cursor = db.collection.find({"creationDate": {$exists: false}});
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
          box = cursor.next();
          box.creationDate = new Date();
          db.collection.save(box);
    }
```

All 100 documents are saved successfully.

when I enter this query in database, I get the correct result:

```
db.collection.find({'creationDate' : {$exists: true}})
```

but when I execute this line in java (using mongodb java driver 2.12), it returns nothing:

```
myCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("creationDate", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));
```

Though when I added field creationDate using mongodb java driver to one of my documents, the above code returns only that document.

My entity class that is stored in database looks like this:

```
public class Entity {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String identifier;

    private Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>(1);

    private Date creationDate;

    //setters and getters
}
```

My question is: Why doesn't mongodb java driver recognize my newly added field in database?

(sorry for my poor English!)

Comment: Can you show the code you use to add/update a document with the date field?
And also could you show the code you use to iterate over the cursor (I think collection.find(...) returns a cursor).

Comment: Can you please show the Java code too? How do you check whether the result (cursor) is empty?

Also can you confirm you are querying the same database and the same collection in both environments (Mongo shell and Java program) ?

Comment: @Elyasin I use this line to get my collection: DBCollection myCollection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collection"); myCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("creationDate", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));

Comment: @Elyasin Yes, I can, because when I write other queries such as myCollection.count(new BasicDBObject("creationDate", new BasicDBObject("$exists", false))); it returns number of all entities in myCollection, which is in conflict with what I get in mongodb shell.

Comment: is `myCollection` and `collection` was same ?

Comment: @RoyaJavadi Can you tell us what you get when you invoke toString() on the BasicDBObject? Like so e.g.: 

new BasicDBObject("creationDate", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)).toString();

Comment: Could you slim down your code to a [simple but complete (i.e.: "compilable") example and provide few sample test data](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we could test it ourselves. As it is now, this is not reproducible. At least to me.